# Firebase Sign Out Google

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner programmer and I have a problem. How do I do google logout functions in the Activity Menu? 
I sit on this problem for a long time and somehow I can't deal with it.
The Activity menu is used to show user information..

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SignInButton signInButton;
    public GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        signInButton=(SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);


        createRequest();


        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    }


    private void createRequest() {


        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();


        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {


        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry auth failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }


                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Menu Activity

logoutBtn is the button that after clicking will be used to log out the user from Google and chew him to MainActivity so that he can choose there again which account he wants to log into my application

```
Button logoutBtn;
    TextView userName;
    ImageView profileImage;
    ImageButton play_button, multi_button, statistic_button, option_button;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        logoutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);


        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if(signInAccount != null) {
            userName.setText(signInAccount.getDisplayName());
            //mail.setText(signInAccount.getEmail());

        }



        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could conveniently use this for logout (details are here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) :

```
AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            // ...
        }
```

For fragment, "this" would have to be replaced with `requireContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    ...

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAuth.signOut();
    });
}
```